# Auto-indent HTML Code and Display It

Tags: php, html, formatting, html-parsing

When displaying HTML code in PHP, if I want to indent tags what would be the best way?

For example,

```
<?php
$html = '<div><p><span>some text</span></p></div>';

echo htmlspecialchars($html);
?>
```

will give `<div><p><span>some text</span</p></div>`.

Instead, I'd like to show something like,

```
<div>
    <p>
        <span>some text</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tidying HTML5 Output Indentation in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116599/tidying-html5-output-indentation-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use htmLawed
http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/

this would be your code:

```
<?php
  require("htmLawed/htmLawed.php");
  echo "<pre>";
  echo htmlspecialchars(
         htmLawed('<div><p><span>some text</span></p></div>', array('tidy'=>4))
       );
  echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks. One thing making me concern is that it's licensed under LGPL. That means if I use the code, my whole project has to be open source and let people modify my work and distribute the modified version of it. I let this question unsolved for a while in case somebody else can provide code that seems to be easier to adapt it for my project.

Comment: Doesnt LGPL only say, that you must name the Author of that library? (I think you don't have to open your whole sourcecode to the public, only because you use one LGPL Library in it)

Comment: I'm not sure. It's very confusing for me to understand how to use a LGPL licensed library. Even it doesn't say how to attribute the author. I've been trying searching information about it but it seems the interpretation varies depending on the personal opinion in the end. This is a different topic. And I appreciate your information so far.

Comment: htmLawed has dual LGPL (version 3) and GPL (version 2 or higher) license. Under LGPL, htmLawed can be 'used by' a non-(L)GPLed software (free or not). The software, in its text(s) for license/copyright, does need to attribute the author and mention the license of htmLawed . If htmLawed is modified and the modified version used in the distributed software, then the modified version of htmLawed remains under (L)GPL; i.e., its modified source should be open.

Comment: Note that with rubo77's code, htmLawed will perform other actions on the input besides tidying (such as sanitizing of the HTML). If you want to use just the tidy functionality of htmLawed, you may want to use the hl_tidy function of htmLawed: `$out = hl_tidy($in, 't', 'div');`

Comment: @Teno If you are making websites, you are technically not distributing your code, so you do not need to disclose your source under the GPL etc.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to use the HEREDOC.

```
 $html = <<<NICE

 <div>
     <p>
         <span>some text</span>
     </p>
 </div>

 NICE;

 echo "<pre>";
 echo htmlspecialchars( $html );
 echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to know [PHP Tidy extension](http://id.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php).

Tidy is a binding for the Tidy HTML clean and repair utility which allows you to not only clean and otherwise manipulate HTML documents, but also traverse the document tree.

Comment: I'd like to do it without extension if possible. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Teno Sorry I know it's an old question, but Tidy is a native Php extension. You prefere to avoid extensions but you accepted an answer that uses an external library.... I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how you want it to be output (as in what your string will look like as you make it), you can easily do it like this:

```
$html = "<div>\n\t\t<p>\n\t\t\t<span>some text</span>\n\t\t</p>\n\t</div>";
```

Be sure to use double quotes though, not single ones.

Output as viewed in source code:

```
<div>
    <p>
        <span>some text</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

If you want to have it done automatically, then you might have to hold out for another answer, I don't really know much regex to help, and I don't use DOM (not even sure if it is applicable in this situation).

Comment: The strings I want to modify are rather dynamic. Thanks for the comment.