# Want to print html code as output of echo statement in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to print some html code which i stored in database, when ever i try to print that variable through its returning the compiled result of HTML code.

CODE SNIP :

```
$html = '<html><body><h1>hello</h1></body></html>'(this one store in db)
echo $html;
```

OUTPUT:
hello in h1 format

But I want 
`'<html><body><h1>hello</h1></body></html>'` this as output.

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Use `htmlspecialchars` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead

```
echo $html;
```

Use that

```
echo htmlspecialchars($html);
```

Comment: thank you is there any way i can print line wise i.e in line 1 <html> line <body>...so on

Comment: Its possible using ```htmlawed```  Here the referance https://github.com/kesar/HTMLawed/blob/master/htmLawed.php

Comment: Referance solution :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175190/auto-indent-html-code-and-display-it

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
echo htmlspecialchars($html);
```