# New line but keep the previous lines indentation

Tags: php, html

I have a function which builds most of my application head:

```
 function header() {
         $html = "<title>Test</title>\r\n";
         $html .= "<link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'>\r\n";
         return $html;
 }
```

Now this works great, but either all the content is in 1 line (if I remove the \r\n) or they fall on the next new line (as expected) but it looses the indentation.

Is there a way for me to keep the previous lines indentation? It's purely just for presentation sake (not needed for the functionality)

Comment: Take a look at [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116599/tidying-html-5-output-indentation-in-php) asked essentially the same thing it looks like. The accepted answer mentions the [PHP Tidy extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php), which you may find useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
function header() {
     $html  = "<title>Test</title>\r\n";
     $html .= "<link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'>\r\n";
     $html .= "  <foo>\r\n";
     $html .= "    <bar/>\r\n";
     $html .= "  </foo>\r\n";
     // ...
     return $html;
}
```

to keep the indention (in this case 2 spaces, as I like it most with html ;). Meaning that you'll have to add to indention to php's output explicetly.

Answer (score 1):

In order of least preferred to most preferred. You can use:

- spaces/tabs (`\t`)
- heredoc/nowdoc syntax
- beautifier
- template engine